# re-init simplemodal

Tags: jquery, ajax, simplemodal

regarding this jquery plugin
http://www.ericmmartin.com/simplemodal-1-4-3-released/

I have an ajax function which takes a little while to get the data - so i want to open the modal div with a spinner

```
$("#basic-modal-content").modal(); 
$("#basic-modal-content").html('<img src="ajax_loader.gif" width=100>');
```

within the ajax call at the end in the success function, I make this

```
$('#basic-modal-content').empty();
$('#basic-modal-content').html('<div class="content-center">'+title+'</div>');
$("#basic-modal-content").modal();
```

this results in
1. popup open with spinner - thats ok
2. the basic-modal-content div gets empty
3. the new content get loaded
4. the content is much to long for the div

normally with the first modal call, the content is ewithin the div with a scrollbar.

so, is tehre any option I can re-initialisate the modal call?

thanks
Adrian

Comment: Maybe you can just put "overflow: auto" or something on the #basic-modal-content ..?

Comment: gimme credits ;) haha. Yw! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply went to the [demopage](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/) and tried to reproduce the problem, and ofcourse try to find the problem and fix it.

Reproducing was just making the content to be 2000px high.

The following worked for me in this particular case:

```
overflow: auto;
```